# How to apply a super simple input validation in React

Tags: reactjs, validation

I have started with ES6 not too long ago + React and I'm having a difficulty applying the methodology for validation on this form, I am using [Validator.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) and the issue isn't syntax but rather the methodology of how/where to pass these validation between state and props and when.

#### I've built the form as follows:

App.js calls in the `ComponentForm` that calls `FormErrors` as a child component, I have started declaring fields yet I have no idea where to apply the validations, I would be happy to get the incoming errors from my simple `FormErrors` component.

Irrelevant consts/vars (api key, email msg, etc) have been removed for brevity.

### my Form:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import validator from 'validator';
import FormError from './FormErrors';
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');

//require('../.env').config();

class ComponentForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            fName: '',
            lName: '',
            email: '',
            tel: '',
            formErrors: {
                email: 'Please Enter a correct Email',
                name: 'Names are only Alphabet characters',
                tel: 'Telephone is only numeric'
            },
            emailValid: false,
            nameValid: false,
            telValid: false
        };

        const SENDGRID_API_KEY = "bla bla";
        sgMail.setApiKey(SENDGRID_API_KEY);

        this.changeValue = this.changeValue.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    };

    changeValue = event => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    onSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ( !validator.isEmail(this.state.email)){
            console.log('email is NOT valid!');
        }

        const msg = {bla:bla};
        //sgMail.send(msg);
        console.log('mail sent!');
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input
                    placeholder="First Name"
                    value={this.state.fName}
                    name="fName"
                    onChange={event => this.changeValue(event) }
                    onKeyPress={this._handleKeyPress}
                /><br/><br/>
                <input
                    placeholder="Last Name"
                    value={this.state.lName}
                    name="lName"
                    onChange={event => this.changeValue(event)}
                /><br/><br/>
                <input
                    placeholder="Email"
                    value={this.state.email}
                    name="email"
                    onChange={event => this.changeValue(event)}
                    error={this.state.emailError}
                /><br/><br/>
                <input
                    placeholder="Telephone Number"
                    value={this.state.tel}
                    name="tel"
                    onChange={event => this.changeValue(event)}
                /><br/><br/>
                <button onClick={(event) => this.onSubmit(event)}>Submit</button>
                <FormError error={this.state.errorType} />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default ComponentForm;
```

### FormError Component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const spacing = 10;
const color = 'red';

class FormErrors extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div style={{marginTop: spacing + 'px', color: color}}>Error Message</div>
        );
    };
}
export default FormErrors;
```

So would it make sense for `FormError` to have the validation logic and apply it?

It may sound bad, but i'm still confused about passing/altering state between components, the state/prop methodology changes from one example to another, so I would be more than happy to get the most **straightforward and simple** example how to apply validation here, not looking for fancy/speed, just want to understand and apply this.

Many Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't you define a validation function in the componentForm and call it from onChange or onSubmit?

Comment: @Rahamin hi, because I am looking for reusability, where `FormErrors` could be extended in the future (makes sense?)

Comment: Ok, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a FormError component, I would define a formError helper function which will get the value to be validated and the field type. Based on the return value you will render/not render the error message in the parent component which renders the form.

If you want to define a child component that will dusplay the error, you can do that as well, passing the validation result and the field type, so that it can render/not render the error message.

Comment: can you intervene in the code above to show how to make that error line switch errors?

Comment: I already have an answer for this, come back later and see. Thx anyhows.